# Angular ErrorHandler http error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular (4.x.x) and I'm struggling with error generated with http requests.

In [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/l7kXmXUF1h6zBysrfvRR) plnkr I tried to summarize a case. I'm generating some errors and trying to record them. When I generate an error due to an http call the angular change detection seems to break and I miss the first http error.

I'm using an ErrorHandler implementation to intercept the error

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomExceptionHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private errMsgService: ErrorMessageService) {
    super();
  }

  public handleError(err: any): void {
    let localErr = err;
    if (err.originalException) {
      localErr = err.originalException;
    }
    if (localErr instanceof CustomException) {
      console.log(`Handling CustomException`);
      // stream errors through the service
      this.errMsgService.addError(localErr);
    } else {
      super.handleError(err);
    }
  }
}
```

and record it in a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorMessageService {
  private errorMessagesEmitter:ReplaySubject<CustomException> = new ReplaySubject<CustomException>();
  errorMessages = this.errorMessagesEmitter.asObservable();

  public addError(err: any) {
    this.errorMessagesEmitter.next(err);
  }
}
```

In the plunker I'm simply listening to the ErrorMessageService and printing the generated error. When the error start from an Http I miss an error.

If I un-commment app.ts line 36, where I force a tick(), the error is visualized correctly.

```
this.errMsgService.errorMessages.subscribe(e => {
  this.errorCount++;
  this.errors.push({ 'error': e, 'count': this.errorCount});
  this.errorToConsole(e);

  // this.appRef.tick();
});
```

Is this the expected behaviour? otherwise what am I doing wrong?

**update**

Looking at recent angular changes, I focused on this: [https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/a1bb9c2].
I decided to try launching my example error handling inside the NgZone and I modified the plnkr

```
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    // stream errors through the service
    this.errMsgService.addError(localErr);
  });
```

With this modification it's working.

Comment: Logic seems ok - and the plunkr works fine for me when generating an http error first (with or without that line commented).

Comment: Hi @Steveland83, thanks for taking a look. Line commented, when I click on "Generate Http Error" I don't see anything in the bottom of the page; at the second click of the same button an error appear.
The behaviour is different for the other buttons, where every click is listed below as an error.
Isn't happening also in your browser? is it my browser problem?

Comment: Looks like it - for me it works fine in Chrome, but fails in IE (and wont load at all in firefox). Check the browser debugging outputs and you should be able to track down the cause.

Comment: Let's hope someone else take a look then. in my environments:
Linux: Firefox 54, Chrome 5x
Windows: Firefox 54, Chrome 59, IE 11
The issue manifests in all browsers